# rrdtool 1.5.4: Several options and operations from manpages do not work

Tags: rrdtool

I'm running rrdtool 1.5.4 (currently in Debian Sid repos and the latest version to be found) on my Sid desktop and my Stable server. I would like to use some of the features the manpages - which mention the same version - and the in-application help advertise, but they simply don't appear to work.

Specifically, I'm talking about the `--source` option to `rrdtool create` and the `--step` option to `rrdtool tune`; furthermore, I would like to modify RRAs with `rrdtool tune`.

The options, however, simply throw `ERROR: unknown option`, despite appearing no different from others on the author's github, to be found here: https://github.com/oetiker/rrdtool-1.x under src/rrd_create and rrd_tune, respectively.

If I issue one of the RRA operations with `rrdtool tune`, say  `rrdtool tune t.rrd RRA:MAX:0.5:10:10` on an empty RRD, I get exactly the same output as when just running `rrdtool tune t.rrd`.

Background: I have several hundred RRD files from when I was still learning the concept that are badly configured, and I'd like to either modify them with `tune` or migrate them to a new RRD with `--source`. I'm aware of `rrdjig`, by the way, but have so far been unsuccessful in its use, and the `--source` option appears to be its intended, more stable replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Apparently, it needs on `librrd4` in the same version as the binary to provide all functions, and since it's a Stable system and I don't think `rrdtool` explicitly specifies the library version it wants, `apt-get` thought the 1.4.8 from Stable was enough.